# Costly performance of CollectionConverters despite being wrappers?

Tags: scala, performance, wrapper, scala-collections, scala-java-interop

AFAIU, [`CollectionConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/jdk/CollectionConverters$.html) are wrappers simply delegating calls to the underlying collection, thus the cost should be single object allocation and then single method call indirection, for example, [Conversion Between Java and Scala Collections](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html) states

> Internally, these conversion work by setting up a “wrapper” object
>   that forwards all operations to the underlying collection object. So
>   collections **are never copied** when converting between Java and Scala.

Analysing [`SetWrapper`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/bc050293f99d6905df096db9c02560c3af854b47/src/library/scala/collection/convert/JavaCollectionWrappers.scala#L130) indeed we see it simply delegates the call to the `underlying` collection

```
class SetWrapper[A](underlying: Set[A]) extends ju.AbstractSet[A] with Serializable { self =>
  ...
  def size = underlying.size
  ...
}
```

However, consider the following jmh benchmark

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations._
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._
import java.{util => ju}

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.Throughput))
class So31830028 {
  val size = 1000000
  val scalaSet: Set[Int] = (1 to size).toSet
  val javaSet: ju.Set[Int]  = (1 to size).toSet.asJava

  @Benchmark def scala = scalaSet.size
  @Benchmark def scalaAsJava = scalaSet.asJava.size
  @Benchmark def java = javaSet.size
  @Benchmark def javaAsScala = javaSet.asScala.size
}
```

where `sbt "jmh:run -i 10 -wi 5 -f 2 -t 1 bench.So31830028"` gives

```
[info] Benchmark                     Mode  Cnt          Score          Error   Units
[info] So31830028.java              thrpt   20  356515729.840 ± 64691657.672   ops/s
[info] So31830028.javaAsScala       thrpt   20  270053471.338 ± 36854051.611   ops/s
[info] So31830028.scala             thrpt   20  448415156.726 ± 53674976.259   ops/s
[info] So31830028.scalaAsJava       thrpt   20  211808793.234 ± 57898858.737   ops/s
```

Why there seems to be a significant performance penalty if `CollectionConverters` are simple wrappers?

<sup>The question is inspired by [Cost of implicit conversion from java to scala collections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31830028/5205022)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2.12, `scalaSet.size` is [just a field access](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/HashSet.scala#L527); for 2.13 it's a trivial field accessor call on [a final class](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.1/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/HashSet.scala#L401), which should be very easy to inline, so

> a single object allocation and then single method call indirection

can be a non-trivial overhead *compared to that*.

What I don't understand is the difference between `java` and `javaAsScala` (edit: duh, it's one more indirection).